# Reading file from within JAR not working on windows

Tags: java, windows, file, jar, classloader

I'm trying to read from a file that is packaged up inside a JAR, along with the class that reads it. To do this, I use the following:

```
getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(file)
```

This works fine when I create and run the JAR file on OSX, but if I create and run the JAR file on windows, the above line returns null.

Am I missing something here? If I create the JAR on OSX and run it on Windows it works fine. The problem only occurs when I create the JAR on windows.

EDIT: It's worth mentioning that there is no folder hierarchy within the JAR file. Everything is stored at one level, thus the class reading the file and the file itself are both in the same directory. Additionally, this is how I'm creating the JAR file, on both OSX and Windows:

```
jar -cmf manifest.mf run.jar *.class file1 file2
```

EDIT 2: The file I am trying to load is a java .properties file. I take it that's not what is causing the issue?

Comment: Jar files are zip files, so you can use that to verify the Windows-created version.  Rename it with a .zip and then browse inside with Windows Explorer.

Comment: @NathanielWaisbrot verify what exactly? That the files are all there? I've checked that (using jar -tf instead), and they're definitely all there, in the structure that I described in the question

Comment: You say that a jar built on the Mac works on Windows, but a jar built on Windows doesn't work.  Diff the contents of the two jar files.  If you're using the same version of Java, I think the .class files should be identical.

Comment: @NathanielWaisbrot diff is telling me they're different, but how can I see which line exactly?

I've just checked, and the windows machine and Mac are running different versions of Java. Though, I can't imagine that would cause the problem?

Comment: You can't just diff the jars.  They will always be different because of the manifest.  You want to diff the internal structure and the individual files.  Maybe just expand the zip file and use ediff.  If you find a difference in a `.class`, use `javap` to disassemble both versions and compare.  The only thing I can imagine is either version mismatch or file encoding as the problem...

Answer (score 0):

Skip the classloader part. Just getClass().getResource....

Comment: I'd `Classloader.getSystemResource()`

Comment: I tried that as well. Same results: works on OSX, not on Windows. I also tried `this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("\file");`, but that didn't work either

Comment: Aha! Don't use any path separators. Just the file name.

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way getClass().getResourceAsStream("/file1").

Answer (score 0):

When using file separators, don't hard code them!
Use java.io.File.separator instead:  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#separator

Comment: File.pathSeparator returns the semi-colon on OS X, which is not intended for the use you tell it is. File.separator returns the slash and is therefore the one to use.